# mutually dependent local classes (or mutually recursive lambdas)

Tags: c++, class, struct, forward-declaration

I often create local helper classes inside methods, wherever such a class is locally useful but irrelevant outside the method. I just came across a case where I would like two local classes  that are mutually dependent.

The idea is to have the following pattern:

```
void SomeClass::someMethod()
{
    struct A
    {
        B * b;
        void foo() { if(b) b->bar(); };
    };
    struct B
    {
        A * a;
        void bar() { if(a) a->foo(); }
    };
}
```

But it doesn't compile because `A` needs `B`. Forward declaring `B` helps so that the line `B * b;` compiles, but still the method `A::foo()` needs the full declaration of `B` and the compiler complains.

I see two workarounds:

1. Declaring and defining the classes in SomeClass.cpp, before `SomeClass::someMethod()`. I feel it's not elegant since not only the classes are not local to `SomeClass::someMethod()`, but not even local to `SomeClass`.
2. Declaring the classes in SomeClass.h nested in `SomeClass`, and defining them in SomeClass.cpp. I do not like this solution either because because not only the classes are not local to `SomeClass::someMethod()`, but it does pollute SomeClass.h for no good reason other than a limitation of the language.

Hence two questions: is it possible at all to have the classes local to `SomeClass::someMethod()`? If not, do you see more elegant workarounds?

Comment: why you need it local inside a method? you can declare/define them in .cpp file only and it don't pollute .h file

Comment: @BryanChen: it's not really that I *need* it, it's just that it is way more elegant if I can: if the class is an implementation details for the method, then defining it inside the method is where it belongs. Just good OOP encapsulation.

Comment: @Boris Its encapsulation, but its not OOP.

Comment: ok it make sense to me. however, this means you will have a big method and you can't unit test struct `A` and `B`

Comment: Still, why do you need two mutually dependent structs? Maybe if you showed a practical usage of this it would be easier to answer.

Comment: @remyabel I need to represent a multigraph. The structs are actually called Node and Edge, a node has a list of incident edges, and an edge has a leftNode and a rightNode. Then I need to do several things on this graph, for instance extract loops. I have a few useful data to store in the nodes and edges during traversal of the graph.

Comment: @Boris Maybe you need three structs then, if you're building a graph. Exactly how much information should a "Node" and "Edge" know about each other?

Comment: @remyabel As I said, the structs are small, and used for convenience inside the method. The idea is not to over-engineer this, reason why making it local and defining it close to where it's used increase readability. :-) Of course I can define all the methods in another class and call graph.foo(a) instead of a->foo(), but since the graph object in itself is useless, it's just less readable for no good reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the answer seems to be: "it is not possible to have clean mutually dependent local classes", it turns out that the workaround I like the most is to move the logic outside the structs themselves. As suggested by remyabel in the comments of the question, it can be done by creating a third class, but my favorite approach is to create mutually recursive lambda functions, since it makes possible to capture variables (hence makes my life easier in my real case usage). So it looks like:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    struct B;
    struct A { B * b; };
    struct B { A * a; };

    std::function< void(A *) > foo;
    std::function< void(B *) > bar;

    foo = [&] (A * a) 
    {
        std::cout << "calling foo" << std::endl;
        if(a->b) { bar(a->b); }
    };
    bar = [&] (B * b)
    {
        std::cout << "calling bar" << std::endl;
        if(b->a) { foo(b->a); }
    };

    A a = {0};
    B b = {&a};
    foo(&a);
    bar(&b);

    return 0;
}
```

That compiles and prints:

```
calling foo
calling bar
calling foo
```

Note that the type of the lambdas must be manually specified because type inference doesn't work well with recursive lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a virtual A, for B to use, then the real A.

```
struct virtA
{
  virtual void foo() = 0 ;
} ;
struct B
{
  virtA * a ;
  void bar() { if ( a) { a->foo() ; } }
} ;
struct A : public virtA
{
  B * b ;
  void bar() { if ( b) { b-> bar() ; } }
} ;
```

Comment: Ah, ok, we have to turn up the horror just a little then.

Answer (score 0):

I used to think this was impossible too, but there was the nagging thought that the Y combinator could be put to good use, it's 2021 now, and constexpr helps create a language within a language that's possibly better than Haskell. Plus it's at the base of a class of problems that occurs often when writing functional language compilers ...

To work towards an optimal solution takes some lateral thinking as to how to crack this chicken/egg situation:

Firstly we can't use auto or templates in local classes, so is there anything we can do instead? We can define lambdas that are functions the type parameter they are sent, ignoring any instance data, allowing them to be constexpr. This means we can define a function that creates the object B, given the type of A ... but we are not finished yet, we still have a data segment to contend with. The class creation function needs to know about this, or we have to explicitly have a using A::i to get the data from the A segment. Thus, just as in assembly code, we have to separate the data and code segments, and since the data has simpler typing, we place it first in the list of dependencies, and derive it twice as a virtual base class, one of the few (only?) valid uses I've found for a virtual base class (a pattern best avoided, but here, unavoidable?).

Then we essentially work with the first iteration of the Y combinator. Inside the context of A::foo, we use the class extender crB to create the precise type of the B object, and casts this to a pointer of that type to "call" it.

Here's where it gets interesting. If the code is sufficiently well typed, the compiler can deduce we are intending a mutual tail recursion, and elide the call to a jmp, a process that is critical for correctly targeted functional code.

Using std::function, which is implemented using a compiler unfriendly virtual function call, scuppers any chances of this optimization, so perhaps this method is more friendly, since the compiler has access to all the types involved, without any indirection?

```
  #include <iostream>
  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  {      
     struct Data
     {
        int i = 563;
     };

     constexpr auto crB = [](auto par)
     {
        using T = decltype(par);

        struct B :  public T, virtual public Data
        {
           void foo() {
              std::cerr << "B: " << i << "\n";
              i = (3 * i) + 1;
              T::foo();
           }
        };
        return B();
     };

     struct A : virtual public Data
     {
        void foo()
        {
           std::cerr << "A: " << i << "\n";

           i >>= 1;

           if (i == 1)
              return;
           using ForwardT = decltype(crB(A()));
           (i&1)? static_cast<ForwardT *>(this)->foo() : foo();
        };
     };

     auto binst = crB(A());

     binst.foo();

     return 0;
  }
```

So what does this high level assembly language compile to?

```
  .LC0:
        .string "B: "
  .LC1:
        .string "\n"
  .LC2:
        .string "A: "
  main::{lambda(auto:1)#1}::operator()<main::A>(main::A) const::B::foo():
        push    rbx
        mov     rbx, rdi
  .L3:
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cerr
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
        mov     rdi, rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbx]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax-24]
        mov     esi, DWORD PTR [rbx+rax]
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbx]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rax-24]
        add     rdx, rbx
        imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rdx], 3
        inc     eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], eax
  .L4:
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cerr
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
        mov     rdi, rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbx]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax-24]
        mov     esi, DWORD PTR [rbx+rax]
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbx]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rax-24]
        add     rdx, rbx
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdx]
        sar     eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], eax
        cmp     eax, 1
        je      .L1
        test    al, 1
        je      .L4
        jmp     .L3
  .L1:
        pop     rbx
        ret
  main:
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     rdi, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], OFFSET FLAT:vtable for main::{lambda(auto:1)#1}::operator()<main::A>(main::A) const::B+24
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], 563
        call    main::{lambda(auto:1)#1}::operator()<main::A>(main::A) const::B::foo()
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
  _GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
        push    rax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init() [complete object constructor]
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        pop     rcx
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
        jmp     __cxa_atexit
  typeinfo for main::Data:
        .quad   vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info+16
        .quad   typeinfo name for main::Data
  typeinfo name for main::Data:
        .string "*Z4mainE4Data"
  typeinfo for main::A:
        .quad   vtable for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info+16
        .quad   typeinfo name for main::A
        .long   0
        .long   1
        .quad   typeinfo for main::Data
        .quad   -6141
  typeinfo name for main::A:
        .string "*Z4mainE1A"
  typeinfo for main::{lambda(auto:1)#1}::operator()<main::A>(main::A) const::B:
        .quad   vtable for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info+16
        .quad   typeinfo name for main::{lambda(auto:1)#1}::operator()<main::A>(main::A) const::B
        .long   2
        .long   2
        .quad   typeinfo for main::A
        .quad   2
        .quad   typeinfo for main::Data
        .quad   -6141
  typeinfo name for main::{lambda(auto:1)#1}::operator()<main::A>(main::A) const::B:
        .string "*ZZ4mainENKUlT_E_clIZ4mainE1AEEDaS_E1B"
  vtable for main::{lambda(auto:1)#1}::operator()<main::A>(main::A) const::B:
        .quad   8
        .quad   0
        .quad   typeinfo for main::{lambda(auto:1)#1}::operator()<main::A>(main::A) const::B
    .quad   0
    .quad   typeinfo for main::{lambda(auto:1)#1}::operator()<main::A>(main::A) const::B
```

All the tail recursive calls have been elided. The translation is essentially perfect.